# Which platforms implement flock?

Tags: c, flock

I'm looking at the Ruby MRI code for [`File#flock`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-i-flock). The documentation states that it's "Not available on all platforms.", but doesn't state which. If I should venture a guess, old FAT file systems might not have locking, but I would like to not be guessing.

Digging a bit into the implementation takes me to [`rb_file_flock(VALUE obj, VALUE operation)`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/file.c#4264), which in turn calls [`rb_thread_flock(void *data)`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/file.c#4203). This simply wraps a call to `flock` from `sys/file.h`. However, it seems that this implementation may or may not be available:

```
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_FILE_H
# include <sys/file.h>
#else
int flock(int, int);
#endif
```

However, I can't figure out where `HAVE_SYS_FILE_H` is defined (In a build-script perhaps?), so I don't know which platforms would enable it.

So, for my question(s): Which platforms could I expect `HAVE_SYS_FILE_H` to be defined for. And provided that it *is* defined and thus `sys/file.h` available, can I expect file locking to work?

Comment: Are you asking for an enumeration of *all platforms*? Including gameboys and toasters?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure where to draw the line. I suppose I'm only interested in platforms for which Ruby could be compiled, but I'm not sure how to present such a list. Realistically, I suppose something like osx, linux, *bsd, windows and solaris would cover any real world cases, judging from this page: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/installation/

Answer (score 0):

[`flock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) is a BSD and Linux extension function:

> CONFORMING TO
>
> 4.4BSD (the flock() call first appeared in 4.2BSD).  A version of flock(), possibly implemented in terms of fcntl(2), appears on most UNIX systems.

Unix specification **does require** advisory file locking to be implemented in terms of [`fcntl(F_SETLK)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html):

> Record locking **shall** be supported for regular files, and may be supported for other files.

Comment: Thanks - So that would cover all unices, I suppose - including bsd and osx? But where does that leave windows?

Comment: You could use autoconf to find out whether the function is available. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15606859/412080

Comment: Yeah, but my question is backwards - I need to know how ruby mri does it. Unless you're saying that they use autoconf?

Comment: OK - I see flock mentioned twice in https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/configure.in but I'm really in the deep end as to interpreting this file. How does ac get from that and to defining a constant `HAVE_SYS_FILE_H`? Or really - which platforms would that happen for?

Comment: @troelskn I wish I could explain you `autoconf` in three sentences... Check out its documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I think we're getting close to my actual problem here :P

Comment: @troelskn You can download the sources, run `./configure` and then check `config.log`. In there you can find the sources of a C program it compiles and runs to determine whether `flock` is available.